# AndroidManifest no resource found

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

Ia m building react native app thats compatible with both ios and android platforms. But when I am trying to Build signed APK on Android Studio for Android platform then I am getting No resource found error in AndroidManifest file even though these files exist - anyone any idea ?

[image: click to enlarge]

[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0NQi.png)

Comment: There is a typo in the manifest file. It should mipmap instead of mitmap. Also, please check if there is a AppTheme style declared in values/styles.xml file.

Comment: corrected typo and attached values/styles.xml file still same error

Answer (score 0):

I think this must be a simple typo - you misspelled `mipmap` (you typed **mitmap** instead) - change the line from `android:icon="@mitmap/ic_launcher` into `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher`. Hopefully the other error also disappears after fixing this? Please give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Try cleaning your project and rebuilding - see if the error persists.

Comment: did clean and rebuilt still same :(

Comment: By the way, is it complaining about the parent-style `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` - what error are you getting when you hover your cursor over the highlighted error on your `styles.xml` file?

Comment: Please show us your `gradle` file - did you include dependency `compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"` under dependencies ?

Comment: Attached build.gradle file on to original question please have a look

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see the gradle file? Where's the link?

Comment: just under the screenshot there is link : build.gradle

Comment: I see, try changing it to `"com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.+"` and see if it liked this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run a clean after correcting the typos